# How to redirect all https request to https

Tags: apache, redirect, http-status-code-301, multiple-domains

I am a bit confused right now by all those redirects.

I have one main domain `domainA.com` and all its subdomains secured by a wildcard certificate. But we have multiple domains for foreign countries like `domainA.ch` or `domainA.co.uk`.
These other Domains are redirected via `301` to the main domain, which works fine when the user types one of the following in his address bar:
`domainA.ch, www.domainA.ch or http://domainA.ch`

But if he enters completely `https://domainA.ch` the user gets a `ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID` message.

The one solution would be to a multi-domain-certificate instead of single-domain, but this would financially a big difference.
The other solution is to get all other domains a vhost, secured by letsencrypt and redirected via `.htaccess` to the main domain.

Both solutions don't look "very fine" for me, is there a way to redirect before the browser does the handshake?

Thanks very much

domainA.com.conf:
*prefix = /var/www/vhosts/system/$pool

user = __

group = __

listen = php-fpm.sock

listen.owner = root

listen.group = __

listen.mode = 0660

chdir = /

pm = ondemand

pm.max_children = 5

pm.max_spare_servers = 1

pm.min_spare_servers = 1

pm.process_idle_timeout = 10s

pm.start_servers = 1*

Comment: In your apache config do you have different files for domainA.ch? For example domainA.ch.conf and domainA.ch-ssl.conf?

Comment: No just from the main-domain, so domainA.com.conf

Comment: Can you edit your question and paste your domainA.com.conf? remove sensitive information

Comment: Done, doesnt look to me as it would help ?! :)

Comment: are you using a webpanel? or is this the config that you find at /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/domainA.com.conf? sorry for asking but never seen an apache config like this

Comment: its from plesk onyx yes, sorry forgot to mention
the /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ just has a 000-default.conf

Comment: can't you disable your SSL over https://domainA.ch?

Comment: It is PHP-FPM configuration.
Anyway, why not secure each domain with separate Let's Encrypt certificate?

Comment: Thanks at you both
@ElvisPlesky mentioned that solution above, thought there was another clean way to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have different IP address for each domain - then each one of them can have there own certificate.  Otherwise you need a SAN certificate for that single IP address.

Comment: He needs a SAN certificate, but not for the IP address. Instead it should have one SAN for each TLD.

Comment: Just to clarify - single IP address can only serve 1 certificate.. so if you have 3 domains on 3 different IP address on a single machine then you can serve 3 different certificate.

Comment: With SNI you can have multiple certificates on the same IP. (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication)

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a wildcard cert that matches different top level domains.

When the client browser connects to https://domain.ch, it needs to see a certificate that includes that domain in the subject or a Subject Alternate Name (SAN).

So there is no easy redirect configuration for your https traffic without the correct certificate. 
If you have a lot of TLD domains that you just want to redirect to your global site, you should take a look at other options. Let's Encrypt certificates might be the way to go.